# Jquery Sortable elements across two accordions

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am using a code to make the elements of an accordion sortable. However, I want the elements to be sortable across both accordions, but that doesn't seem possible with the way it is coded. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<script>
var stop = false;
$("#accordion h3").click(function(event) {
    if (stop) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        stop = false;
    }
});
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "> div > h3"
    })
    .sortable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: "h3",
    stop: function() {
        stop = true;
    }
});

var stop = false;
$("#accordion2 h3").click(function(event) {
    if (stop) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        stop = false;
    }
});
$("#accordion2").accordion({
    header: "> div > h3"
    })
    .sortable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: "h3",
    stop: function() {
        stop = true;
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#accordion,#accordion2").sortable({
                connectWith: "#accordion,#accordion2",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                }
        });
        $("#accordion,#accordion2").disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

My problem now is that the element still thinks its in the other accordion, so, if I move an element from "accordion" to "accordion2", collapse it, and then try to collapse another element from "accordion", it closes the element we moved.

My guess is that codewise, the element I move is still under "accordion" and behave as such. How could I go about fixing this?